# Visualforce Error Message displaying the save mode instead of displaying the edit mode

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

I'm facing a simple issue where I'm displaying an validation error message from trigger based on some condition in the visualforce page. Upto this it is working fine. But after displaying the error message it is going to the save mode where this shouldn't happen. Here is my page and class

```
<apex:pageMessages id="theMsg"></apex:pageMessages>
  <apex:outputPanel id="theEditView">  
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Details" rendered="{!GrpDetailview}">
        <apex:PageBlockSection >
            <apex:OutputField value="{!GrpRec.AccountNumber}" label="Group #"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!GrpRec.Name}" label="Group Name"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!GrpRec.HBC_Grp_Yr__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!GrpRec.HBC_Grp_Status__c}"/>
           </apex:PageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageblockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!GrpEdit}"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>        
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Details" rendered="{!GrpEditview}">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:OutputField value="{!GrpRec.AccountNumber}" label="Group #"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!GrpRec.Name}" label="Group Name"/>
            <apex:InputField value="{!GrpRec.HBC_Grp_Yr__c}"/>
            <apex:InputField value="{!GrpRec.HBC_Grp_Status__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!GrpEditSave}" rerender="theEditView,theMsg"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>        
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

My Apex class is

```
Public void GrpEditSave()
 {     
     try{
         grpDetailview = true;
         grpEditview=false;                  
         update GrpRec;
     }catch(Exception ex){
         if(ex.getmessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION')){
             String[] errorMsg = ex.getMessage().split('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,');
             String[] errorMsgOnly = errorMsg[1].split(':');
             apexPages.addMessage(new apexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,+errorMsgOnly[0].trim()));             
         }
}
```

Don't know what I'm missing here but the output is like this which is going into the save mode after getting the error message.How should I restrict this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of your try block:

```
 update GrpRec;
 grpDetailview = true;
 grpEditview=false;
```

That way if an error is thrown the boolean flags will not be reset

Comment: so simple. didn't noticed that.Thanks